# Shortcut key to attach the open Excel file in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

What is the shortcut key to attach the currently open Excel file in Outlook?

Answer (score 4):

#### Is there a shortcut key to attach the currently open Excel file in Outlook?

No, there isn't one.

See [Keyboard shortcuts for Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-Outlook-3cdeb221-7ae5-4c1d-8c1d-9e63216c1efd).

Comment: In Outlook, you go to Insert Tab, attach file and include that way. You can't drag an Excel sheet into Outlook e-mail body.